# how to change rows and columns in excel file to a matrix

Tags: excel

I  have a table like this in excel:

```
A   Book1   2
A   Book2   3
B   Book2   1
B   Book3   4
C   Book3   6
C   Book4   4
C   Book5   3
D   Book5   2
```

Now I want to convert the above table to such a table: (it looks like a matrix)

```
    Book1  Book2  Book3  Book4  Book5
A   2      3      0      0      0
B   0      1      4      0      0
C   0      0      6      4      3
D   0      0      0      0      2
```

What can I do?

Comment: I would use a pivot table.

Comment: could you please tell me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @HongOoi suggested, a pivot table would be most appropriate here.

[image]

1. Select the table and go to 'Insert' > 'Insert Pivot table'.
2. Choose a location to put the pivot table in the dialog box which pops up.
3. After clicking on 'OK', click, drag and drop the headings into the different areas. You will see that I dropped 'Header 1' in row labels, 'Header 2' in Column Labels and 'Header 3' in Values.
4. TO put the zeroes in, click in the pivot table, right click and choose 'Pivot Table Options'. Look for "For empty cells show:" and put `0` in there, then 'OK'.

You can copy the pivot table and paste as values to remove the pivot table while keeping the data as is, and do other manipulation should you need to.

Comment: thank you very uch. i do this